What chord progression is this for C# major to C major?
I have a simple chord progression that goes from C# major to C major and repeats. It has a distinct feel, but I am not sure what it could possibly be. The song I'm thinking of is one I composed so I don't have any references for it, but it bounces up and down octaves of C# major for a measure before moving to bouncing on C major for a measure and then repeating. Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to interpret this. Thanks!
Edit: In particular, what key might this be in? Does it maybe reference another scale? Is this a well known combo of chords?

You already described what it is. "It bounces up and down octaves of C# major for a measure before moving to bouncing on C major for a measure and then repeating." That is a valid answer to a "what is it" question. Is there something that you cannot do with this description, and you'd like a somehow different description that would enable you to do something different? What do you want to be able to do? Music theory is more or less systematic descriptions of musical practices, and you already gave a quite accurate, even systematic, description. There could be other kinds of descriptions.

@piiperiReinstateMonica My question mainly lies in trying to figure out why this even works. It's unclear to me what key the song would be in, or if it's changing keys. I'm aware, for example, that a V leads to a I, but if someone said that they were strumming a G major to a C major chord, one might bring up how a V to I is relevant. In my case, I don't see how this combination makes sense. It may even be referencing a different scale than either C major or C# major. And those are the sort of things I'm wondering.

Any two chords alternating can generally work. Repetition legitimizes, after all.

@Ttyl The things you talk about, the "V" and "leading to I" etc., that terminology has been developed for describing a very specific harmonic style that has been very prominent in a certain culture. Your song is something that's not done in that style and culture, so describing it with those terms doesn't necessarily make much sense. You've built a three-wheeled electric motorcycle, but you want to describe it with terms developed for describing flying boats. Where are my floats and flaps, what's the stall speed, how do I feather the propellers? :)

@piiperiReinstateMonica Claiming that all terminology refers only to the style that popularized it to me is not true. In my case a good answer might be "for your three wheeled motorcycle, the wheels help drive the vehicle as in cars beforehand, and even in the more traditional case of your flying boat, the motor acts similarly". The case of V to I was not chosen arbitrarily, nor is it entirely linked to its historical contexts. If this were the case, then the entire idea of ratios in the frequencies of notes being simpler in popular melodies would be a crazy coincidence.

I did not say all terminology. Harmony. The "V" and "I" and that stuff, that language evolved for describing functional harmony, and your chord sequence does not have to be treated and interpreted functionally at all. Functional harmony and common period Western music is not a law of nature, it is cultural, acquired taste, just one style among other styles. Music theory is not natural sciences, it's humanistic, descriptions of what is done in a particular culture. People talking about what people do. Forget simple frequency ratios, it's more like superstitions, not a formula behind good music.

Post example notation of what you're playing or a sample recording. It just sounds like you're describing a "vamp."

What do you hear as the tonal centre, C♯ or C?   I suspect C.
Would you have any trouble in accepting a chord sequence that kept repeating G7 - C?
Do you know about the '♭5 substitution', the thing where a chord with a dominant function can be replaced by one with its root a ♭5 higher?
Or you can just analyze it as 'planing', the thing of it sounding good to move from a chord to one of the same shape  immediately above or below.  Here's a well-known song that's based round that idea.


Could you name the song for those of us to whom it isn't well-known in the least?

The song name is stated in its opening lyrics.  From the show 'Guys and Dolls', notably performed by Frank Sinatra.

You aren't giving the opening lyrics. First lyrics I see is "pray.", which seems to be the very end of a verse. And also, any information about the song is in image form only, there doesn't seem to even be an accessibility description.

The chords could be treated modally, or in a guitar rock kind of way, looking at dots on a fretboard and disregarding tonal centers and whatnot. Or they could be treated as C and Db for flamenco style stuff centering on F minor. Or it could be like, "play the white keys of the piano over the C chord, and play the black keys of the piano over the C# chord". Like Miles explained So What to one of his musicians, "play the white keys in the first part and the black keys in the second part" or something. (which I heard from a Robben Ford interview or clinic video)

It's impossible to say what key it is in without knowledge of the melody and where it tends to resolve.
There are several scales that include the tones in C♯ Major and C Major, but that doesn't define the key of the song.
The chords D♭ Major and C Major do fit with the key of F minor as mentioned in Divizna's answer, but if it isn't tending towards resolution on an F minor chord, that's probably not it.
If it resolves on the C chord, and the melody notes have a preference for E♮ (rather than E♭) then it's probably in C major, more or less.  The D♭ chord may well be a tritone substitution (playing the part of G7) as suggested in Laurence's answer.
Depending again on the notes in your melody, I can think of some "exotic" scale contexts that would include these chords and still resolve on the C Major.  Either would still be considered in the key of C Major:

Phrygian Dominant: This scale includes all the notes of C Major and D♭ Major, plus the B♭. It is a mode (rotation) of the Harmonic Minor scale (which would connect it to the F minor mentioned by Divizna). It's known in Klezmer music as "Freygish".  The contrasting chord (D♭) might also take the form of B♭ minor 7. (B♭-D♭-F-A♭, basically D♭ Major with B♭ in the bass).

Double Harmonic: This scale is identical to Phrygian Dominant, but with a B♮ instead of B♭.


One other context where a D♭ Major chord occurs in C Major is the Neapolitan chord in classical music, but your situation doesn't fit as the D♭M isn't followed by a G Major.

Major chords one semitone apart, though they wouldn't be written as C# and C, often appear in songs in a minor key. I don't trust myself enough with the Roman numbers, so I'm going to go with an example: F and E (very often in that order) in A minor, where the E (or E7) chord then most typically resolves to Ami (F - E - Ami). Transposed to F minor, that would be a Db - C - Fmi progression.
Another thing that happens every now and then is something somewhat similar in the relative major key; a typical progression like that would be, in C major, C - E - F - G. Transposed to Ab major, it goes Ab - C - Db - Eb.
Of course, there's nothing saying that your piece has anything to do with this. In principle, pretty much any chord can appear in a piece in any key. They're just the two most common things that come to mind.


what key might this be in? Does it maybe reference another scale?

You correctly identify the essential questions, but you need to answer these questions yourself. What chord feels like resolving the whole song? If you write a melody that uses notes other than the chord tones, what are they? Do you use the same scale over both chords, or a different one for each?
I would agree the answers of Theodore, Divizna and Laurence cover some of the most common ways to interpret or approach these chords, but I think I can provide some more.

both chords are diatonic in some single scale (Theodore's answers) – e.g. with F harmonic minor, the chords C and Db produce stereotypical "arabic"/"flamenco" type of sound
tritone substitution (Laurence's answer) – in this case Db is in fact some form of G7 with some alterations, which then resolves to the tonic, C
implied tonic (Divizna's answer) – possibly neither of the two chords is the tonic chord, but they gravitate towards another chord, never resolving. A famous example of a song built this way is Jobim's Corcovado (Quiet Nights of Quiet Stars)
modal interchange – Db can be interpreted as borrowed e.g. from C phrygian or locrian mode
common structure (Laurence's answer) – the two chords are connected by their common shape moved in parallel, rather than functional relation. This produces the strongest effect if the resulting progression cannot be interpreted with a more traditional manner. Adding upper structures may help (e.g. Cmaj9 to Dbmaj9). With just a pair of chords, in most cases common structure can be understood as modal interchange, or the other way round.
the upper chord is the tonic – listen e.g. to the verse of Lianne La Havas' Forget, in the key of F#, bouncing between the chords F# and E#. Quite exotic structure: none of the common modal scales include diatonic major chord built on the raised 7th step. While E# is the leading tone, B# is a major 7th above C#, making it difficult to consider E# chord as some form of a dominant. I would say it's a purely non-functional structure, yet, it works great, and the melody flows very smoothly.
at least of the chords is in fact a voicing of another chord a.k.a. the bassist enters the room. Consider the following examples:

Note, that this alone is insufficient to explain the harmony, you still need to use some of the approaches mentioned before. Note also, how the last example justifies spelling the second chord as C#.
there is no tonic or there is no single tonic (the-baby-is-you's comment) – some people believe that e.g. modern pop songs based on repeated 4 chord structures don't really have tonic or key and the force gluing the harmony is endless repetition. This has been discussed on MPT, but I can't remember the exact topics.

If all this feels like splitting hair, consider how each of these approaches implies different choice of scales and different way each of the chords feels.
